# OEIS A000065 sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

What is  OEIS A000065 sequence, could someone explain in layman's language. 
https://oeis.org/A000065
0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 10, 14, 21, 29, 41, 55, 76, 100, 134, 175, 230, 296, 384, 489, 626, 791, 1001, 1254, 1574, 1957, 2435, 3009, 3717, 4564, 5603, 6841, 8348, 10142, 12309, 14882, 17976, 21636, 26014, 31184, 37337, 44582, 53173, 63260, 75174, 89133, 105557

Comment: This is [integer partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)), with 1 subtracted.  It makes sense to subtract one, because perhaps we don't want to count the partition with a single term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partition of $n$ is a way of writing $n$ as a sum of positive integers, where the order of summands doesn't matter.  Thus the partitions of $4$ are
$$ \eqalign{4 &= 4\cr
              &= 3 + 1\cr
              &= 2 + 2\cr
              &= 2 + 1 + 1\cr
              &= 1 + 1 + 1 + 1\cr}$$
There are $5$ of them, and you subtract $1$ so  A000065(4) is $4$.
Note that the offset of this sequence is 0, so the first term listed is
A000065(0)=0, then A000065(1)=0, then A000065(2)=1, then A000065(3)=2, then 
A000065(4)=4.

Answer (score 0):

The $n^{th}$ term is the number of ways of writing $n$ as a sum of positive integers, minus $1$.

For $|x|<1$ it has the generating function: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=\frac{1}{x-1}+\prod_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1-x^n}$$